# How to Scroll start with bottom when page is loaded

Tags: c#, jquery, css, asp.net, ajax

Hi I am doing a social network service using asp.net/c#, I have little problems with message sending.

when i am starting to send message scroll [display like this](https://scontent-b-mxp.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpa1/v/t1.0-9/10906209_1507241386232104_79420700166337212_n.jpg?oh=bd971f020987357dcca17c94ac707564&oe=5536BC0B). when i press send message it shows old message first and [scroll is top](https://scontent-b-mxp.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xap1/v/t1.0-9/10898054_1507241806232062_2461530347045754305_n.jpg?oh=44a103a5524a94e358275da237ab1d74&oe=55297972), but i want newer message it mean's when i page loaded page should be showed new messages first

my aspx codes

```
<div style=" overflow-y:auto; height:368px; margin-top: -50px; border-top-style: groove; border-right-style: groove; border-left-style: groove; width: 602px; margin-left: 0px;" >      
              <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="Repeater1" >
 <ItemTemplate>




     <div style="border-top: thin none #BBCEB3; border-bottom: thin none #BBCEB3; padding: 10px;  width: 548px; margin-top: -10px; right: 10px; left: 10px; border-left-width: thin; margin-left: 15px; background-color: #fffff0; border-left-color: #BBCEB3; border-right-color: #BBCEB3; border-top-style: groove; border-bottom-style: groove;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <br />
                    <div style="width: 58px; height: 40px">
                    <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" Height="59px" ImageAlign="Top" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("SProfilePic") %> ' Width="55px" />
                        </div>
                    <div style="width: 307px;  margin-left: 65px; margin-top: -60px">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Arial" ForeColor="#000066"><%#Eval("SenderName") %> </asp:Label>
                    </div>
                    <div id="status" style=" width: 461px; margin-left: 78px; margin-top: 11px;">&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Font-Italic="False" ForeColor="Black" Font-Size="Medium"><%#Eval("Messages") %> </asp:Label>
                    </div>
                    &nbsp;<div style="margin-left: 400px; background-color: #C0C0C0;">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server"  Text="" Font-Size="Small"><%#Eval("Time") %> </asp:Label>
                    </div>
                </div>




 </ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put server controller there for example this:

```
<asp:Button ID="BtnOutside" runat="server" Text="Random" style="margin-left:-999px;" />
```

And then use

```
Page.SetFocus(Me.BtnOutside.ClientID);
```

To get focus to that button which is not visible to the client because of the negative margin. This should push the scroll bar to the bottom.

Comment: thanks friend, where should i put this page.setfocus code? on code behind file??

Comment: Yes put it there. I guess your Send button does post back? So get focus to the BtnOutSide when you have pressed Send button and the site is doing post back

Comment: what is me keyword? it does not exits

Comment: Try Page.SetFocus(BtnOutside);

Comment: i think we should focus to newest message, why should u used a button? it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your code wherever you want to Focus on -- You can use this

multilple times in the same code set just change the "ID"

---

`<asp:Button ID="FocusBottom" runat="server" Text="Random" style="margin-left:-999px;"`

In the event(button click whatever) put in this.

`Page.SetFocus(FocusBottom);`

Change the (#######) to "ID" you want to call